# Why is the carat '^' not working in LIKE expression in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I created an example [here](http://rextester.com/SZUQ6268) where I am trying to filter OUT the cells that have English vowels (a, e, i, o and u) in it. The code is something like below:

```
CREATE TABLE t
(cola VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ddddd');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('dddda');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('dddde');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ddddi');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('eei');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ffff');

SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE cola LIKE '%[^aeiou]%';
```

From the [documentation of SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql), putting the `^` should remove the records with the vowels, but is not working (because it's returning something like below).

```
cola
-----
ddddd
dddda
dddde
ddddi
ffff
```

But when I changed the query to something like below, it works as expected:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE cola NOT LIKE '%[aeiou]%';
```

and returns something like below:

```
cola
-----
ddddd
ffff
```

Am I misunderstanding the use of `^` here? Thank you in advanced for your explanations!

EDIT: clarified and provided some more detail per admin's request.

Comment: There is no `^` in your query. Please clarifiy.

Comment: `LIKE '%[^aeiou]%'` essentially means `where a character that isn't a, e, i, o or u exists`. The percent is a wild card and the stuff in the square bracket refers to a single character so you're looking for anything followed by a non-vowel followed by anything - in other words, the equivalent of `'%[bcdfg...xyz0123456789:;?...everything that isn't a vowel]%'`. `NOT LIKE '%[aeiou]%'` essentially means `where none of the characters are a, e, i, o or u`. So you're looking for anything that doesn't contain a vowel.

Comment: Hi this is expected behavior  as you are searching like ALL  is not in all to use ^ you have to restrict one side eg .like '%[^a]';  or like '[^a]%'; or  like 'xy[^a]%'... no %[^a]%.

Comment: @Bohemian it is a valid question ....

Comment: @ZLK I understand the distinction now. :) Thanks for your explanation!